# BIND: Setup a nameserver for a subdomain with TXT records

Tags: bind

So, interesting use case here. I'm working on a LetsEncrypt project where a self-hosted nameserver will respond (via CNAME) to DNS requests for the ACME challenge. The intent here is to create a docker container that includes the official Certbot, alpine+bind, and make it easy and quick to accept DNS challenges.

My inexperience with bind is proving to be an issue. Here's what I have fully functional on my root DNS servers (at nsone):

- Domain `example.com` DNS servers of ns1.nsone.com/ns2/ns3/ns4 (for example)
- `acme-challenge.example.com` has an NS record of `acme-dns.example.com` (this redirects any lookup requests)
- `_acme-challenge.example.com` is a CNAME pointing to `_acme-challenge.acme-dns.example.com` (So when LetsEncrypt looks up the _acme-challenge TXT record for a wildcard cert, they'll get a response from the self-hosted DNS server at `acme-dns.example.com`

This is all great, and a test with Python's dnslib shows this is working. However, my problem is getting BIND setup.

I'm using https://github.com/resyst-it/docker-bind9, which is just a basic bind on alpine structure. Here are my configs:

named.conf

```
options {
    directory "/var/bind";
    listen-on { 127.0.0.1; };
    listen-on-v6 { none; };
    allow-transfer {
            none;
    };
    pid-file "/var/run/named/named.pid";
    allow-recursion { none; };
    recursion no;
};

zone "acme-challenge.example.com" IN {
  type master;
  file "/zonefile.txt";
};
```

zonefile.txt

```
; acme-challenge.example.com
$TTL 60
acme-challenge.example.com. IN     SOA    a.root-servers.net. nospam@iwishspamdidntexist.com. (
                            2018040201  ; Serial
                            3H          ; refresh after 3 hours
                            1H          ; retry after 1 hour
                            1W          ; expire after 1 week
                            60)         ; minimum TTL of 1 day

    ; Name Server
    IN      NS      acme-dns.example.com.

acme-challenge.example.com.                 IN A            1.1.1.1         
_acme-challenge             IN TXT                  testA
_acme-challenge             IN TXT                  testB

; EOF
```

I really just need a set of config files that will return a record, any record, that is TXT and responds with two answers.

Can anyone help out?

Comment: What are you getting when you query this DNS container? I noticed your `listen` statement is configured for `127.0.0.1`, I'm pretty sure you need `0.0.0.0` or `any` to resolve things on the local network. Maybe it's a docker thing though? I'm not familiar with the intricacies of docker/docker networking.

Comment: Please be more specific. Provide what DNS query you do (and how), what results you get that you did not want and what results you wanted instead.